# How to put comment in a line-continuation

Tags: matlab

I have some function like this:

```
result = myfunc(arg1, ...
                arg2, ...
                arg3);
```

I wish to comment out arg2 and put in something else:

```
result = myfunc(arg1, ...
         %      arg2, ...    <-- I get a red squiggly underline at the last dot
                arg2b, ...   <-- and under arg2b
                arg3);       <-- and under the closing parenthesis
```

But matlab won't let me put a comment in a line continuation, and all my Google searches turn up either multi-line statements, or multi-line comments, but not comments in a multi-line statement.

The error is "Parse error at : usage might be invalid Matlab syntax".

Is there a way to do this?

In reality the arguments are long filenames with full paths, and moving them up and out of the way makes the code really unreadable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To comment out part of a statement that spans multiple lines, use an ellipsis (...) instead of a percent sign. For example,

```
result = myfunc(arg1, ...
            ... arg2, ...
                arg2b, ...
                arg3);
```

Comment: So easy, yet so *not* obvious!! thanks :)